# If condition to check if all values of one list is present in another list

Tags: c#, list, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to write a if condition. It should enter the if condition only if all Nationalities in nationalities List [A,B,C] is available in separate List.

CASE 1 : If SeparateList contains[A,B,C,D,E] and if nationalities List contains [A,B,C], all values in nationalities List is avialable in SeparateList. Therefore it should satisfy 'if' condition.

CASE 2 :If SeparateList contains[A,C,D,E] and if nationalities List contains [A,B,C], B value in nationalities List is not avaIlable in SeparateList. Therefore it should not satisfy 'if' condition.

But currently my if condition is satisfying case 2. I think it is because of Intersect.
So please suggest any ideas.

```
 nationalities.Add(nation.ToUpper().Trim()); //contains list of nationalities [A,B,C]
    
 if(nationalities.Intersect(separateList(bg.Nationality)).Any()) 
{
// code 
}

private List<string> separateList(string input)
        {
            return input.ToUpper().Trim().Split(',').ToList();
        }
```

Comment: I don't get your case 2, neither is "B value in nationalities List" (it is not), nor "B value [...] is not avaIlable in SeparateList" (it is)

Comment: Yeah, made an error in case 2 condition. Its corrected now.

Comment: OK. Using `Except` instead of `Intersect` should do the trick

Comment: Agree `Except` will proof it like: 
`containsAll = !nationalities.Except(separateList).Any();`
or 
`containsAll  = separateList.Union(nationalities).Count() == separateList.Count`

Comment: For bonus points, use `.Except(separateList, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).Any()` and scrap those calls to `ToUpper()`

Comment: @lidqy `if (!nationalities.Except(separateList(bg.Nationality)).Any())` -- This is not getting the bg.Nationality values. Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: Look at the bottom two solutions, either will be better than the original answer*

---

Either `Intersect` the 2 lists, and ensure the length of the intersection matches the length of `nationalities`, or use Linq `All` method do do similar.

Either of these:

```
private static bool Test1(IEnumerable<string> separateList, IEnumerable<string> nationalities)
{
    return separateList.Intersect(nationalities).Count() == nationalities.Count();
}

private static bool Test2(IEnumerable<string> separateList, IEnumerable<string> nationalities)
{
    return nationalities.All(n => separateList.Contains(n));
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jt5mpX

Yet another way, using `Except`

```
private static bool Test3(IEnumerable<string> separateList, IEnumerable<string> nationalities)
{
    return !nationalities.Except(separateList).Any();
}
```

And one more for luck (this is the one to choose for large datasets)!

```
private static bool Test4(IEnumerable<string> separateList, IEnumerable<string> nationalities)
{
    return new HashSet<string>(nationalities).IsSubsetOf(separateList);
}
```

Comment: I have given like this `if(nationalities.All(n => separateList(bg.Nationality).Contains(n)))` and its not satisfying case 1 itself.

Comment: @ClarkeGriffin isnt `bg.Nationality` a comma separated string in your code? In which case you need to `Split(",")` as per your original question.

Comment: `nationalities.Add(nation.ToUpper().Trim()); `//contains list of nationalities [A,B,C]
    
`if(nationalities.All(n => separateList(bg.Nationality).Contains(n)))
{
// code 
}
`
`private List<string> separateList(string input)
        {
            return input.ToUpper().Trim().Split(',').ToList();
        }`    There is some issue with bg.Nationality. I am not getting bg.Nationality value. Please suggest.